# Regex to capture anchor text in quotes

Tags: php, regex, anchor

I am trying to come up with a regex to catch anchors with quoted texts. For example:

```
<a href="www.example.com">this is "some quoted anchor text" example</a>
<a href="www.example.com">this is “another” example with different quote type</a>
```

I came up with this one here but it feels bloated and not working properly in my php 5.5.9 environment:

https://regex101.com/r/NugIi2/3

I am sure there is a better way to catch these quoted anchor texts.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I need to fix errors on AMP pages that I am getting due to anchors texts with quotes. So no DOM manipulation is possible in this case. To be precise I am using worpdress the_content filter with preg_replace at the backend.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML, use `DOMDocument`.

Comment: @JModi this is not a duplicate. It's more specific in that it wants to match the visible text of the anchor *if that visible text contains quotes.*

Comment: Pull out your anchors (see what I did there?) using an HTML parser and *then* parse those using a regex...it becomes much simpler at that point:  something like:  `^.*?"[^"]+?".*?$`

Comment: If there is only one quote in the text: this should work: `(?<=>)(?:.*?)["“](.*?)["”](?:.*)(?=<)` [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NugIi2/5)

Comment: As I have said in the edit I need to fix errors on AMP pages that I am getting due to anchors texts with quotes. So no DOM manipulation is possible in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geez... Literally hours later, I managed to hack together a working DomDocument solution!  If there is a cleaner way that maintains accuracy, I welcome anyone to let me know.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kXlLb))

```
$html=<<<HTML
<a href="bla">123 "this" is asd</a>
<a href="bla">this should not be captured</a>
<a href="bla">no quotes in anchor text here</a>
<a href="bla">"445 is in quotes"</a>
<a href="bla">asd "blabla" sometimes</a>
<a href="bla">Je commence à avoir mal à la tête</a>
<a href="bla">something with quotes like “blabla” is bad</a>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$html=mb_convert_encoding($html,'HTML-ENTITIES',"UTF-8");   // for multibyte chars
$dom->loadHTML($html,LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); // remove DOCTYPE, but allow <html><body> tags for stability
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
    if(preg_match('~["“”]~u',$a->nodeValue)){
        $remove[]=$a;  // collect the nodes to remove
    }
} 
foreach($remove as $bad_a){
    $bad_a->parentNode->removeChild($bad_a); // remove targeted nodes
}
$result=mb_convert_encoding($dom->saveHTML(),"UTF-8",'HTML-ENTITIES');  // for multibyte chars
echo preg_replace(['~^<html><body>|</body></html>$~','~\R+~'],['',"\n"],$result);  // mop up <html> and <body> tags, and consecutive newline characters
```

Output:

```
<a href="bla">this should not be captured</a>
<a href="bla">no quotes in anchor text here</a>
<a href="bla">Je commence à avoir mal à la tête</a>
```

---

Or if you don't want to mess with all of that, here is a regex one-liner that will perform as intended:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/acIHN))

```
echo preg_replace('~<a[^>]*>.*?["“”].*?</a>\R?~u','',$html);
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8DJC1M/1)

Comment: @Barmar if you know a better way or have any suggestions please let me know.  I am rather under-skilled in DomDocument witchcraft, but I am teaching myself by doing/researching.

Comment: Thank you for the regex pattern and detailed answer. It should be working on my backend but for some reason I could not get it to work with wordpress - the_content filter. But anyway this was the regex I have been looking for. Thanks again!